# How to delete a universe in business objects R3 and how to export the universe from local machine to BO repository

Tags: sql-server, oracle, business-objects, sapb1

I have modified the universe in local machine in designer from oracle to sql server. i want to export the universe which is pointing to SQL server.Do i have to delete the existing universe.
Can any body give me some steps how to do this

Thanks 
AK

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to delete the existing universe.  As long as you have the correct rights in Business Objects you should be able to export the universe and it will overwrite the existing one.

You may need to grant rights on the new connection after the export is complete to be able to use the updated universe.